# Find all repositories I have contributed to in an organization on GitHub

Tags: github

I am a member of a GitHub organization.  I would like to list all the repositories I have contributed to.  I have tried searches like:

```
  org:<org-name> user:<user-name>
  org:<org-name> @<user-name>
```

which return ALL the repositories for the organization.  I have also tried:

```
  org:<org-name> <user-name>
```

which returns repositories that include `<user-name>` in the name of the repository.  The other results like `Commits` and `Issues` are equally unhelpful throughout.

Is there a way to find my contribution repositories without resorting to API calls?

Comment: Have you found a way? I'm also interested in doing this query in an organization. Too many repos I want to see only those where I contributed

Comment: i have not.  upvoting this question might get it some more exposure.